# Format UtcNow to display GMT+xx:xx

Tags: c#

I have that line of code that works perfectly fine

```
var datetimenow = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'GMT'K");

result: 2021-05-06T19:31:34GMT+00:00
```

Now I'm trying to do the same thing with UtcNow but the formatting doesn't work

```
var datetimeutc = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'GMT'K");
result: 2021-05-06T19:36:09GMTZ
```

how can I get the same result when I use UtcNow ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it didn't worked is since it is in UTC. The tailing Z means the time didn't have an offset or offset can be equal to 00:00

```
var datetimenow = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'GMT'K");
var datetimeutc = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'GMT+00:00'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the proper explanation and the solution

Comment: Hi, thanks, but you are hard coding the GTM in the string here. I want it be adjusted to where ever you are in the world.

Comment: UTC offset is always 00:00 wherever you are in the world

Answer (score 0):

The 'Z' stands for UTC, i. e. offset +00:00. You could just put in the '+00:00' in the literal string if you do not want to show the 'Z':

```
var datetimeutc = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'GMT+00:00'");
```